# Forge - don't render small elements

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way to set up the viewer so that it doesn't render small elements like bolts?

I have tried progressive rendering which is great but was wondering if there is an options to programmatically exclude elemtns smaller than a certain size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewer has recently introduced [Selective Loading](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-feature-selective-loading) which lets you specify a *property* filter and/or a *spatial* filter for what parts of a design should be loaded. You could use the ["$extent"](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/selective-loading/#spatial-query-language) property to only load fragments with bounding box volume above certain threshold.